# Como acceder desde mi contenedor docker a puertos externos propios de mi computadora?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

tengo un contenedor de docker con el puerto mapeado del 8080 al 8084 ( el 8080 es propio de la imagen y 8084 el accedo en mi maquina) he creado una api de prueba coprriendo en el puero 5000 en mi maquina, seria  http://localhost:5000/ y lo que necesito es acceder a esta api desde mi contenedor de docker, entendi que se hacia con http://host.docker.internal:5000 pero no me da resultado.

Comment: Puedes usar el localhost de la maquina en donde se está ejecutando el docker si en el `run` le pasas `--network host`. De esta manera puedes acceder directamente a http://localhost:5000/

Comment: amigo comentalo como respuesta y te de doy la mejor repsuesta. muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Linux puedes usar el localhost de la maquina en donde se está ejecutando el docker si en el run le pasas `--network host` [fuente](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). De esta manera puedes acceder directamente a localhost:5000 o cualquier otro puerto local.

```
docker run --network host <imagen>
```

En mac y windows se puede usar `docker.for.mac.localhost` y `docker.for.win.localhost` respectivamente para acceder al localhost "anfitrion", pero no lo he testeado. Si alguien lo confirma o no, deje un comentario.